# Loading an embedded resource SVG image wont appear

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin.forms

Loading an embedded resource PNG image into any view works fine, but when i try to load an embedded resource SVG image it wont appear any reasons why !

this code works fine

```
 Image devimage= new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("DOTFORMS3.Icons.developers.png") };
```

but this code wont make the svg image appears

```
Image devimage= new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("DOTFORMS3.Icons.developers.svg") };
```

i even tried this code still nathing !

```
 SvgCachedImage devimage= new SvgCachedImage() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("DOTFORMS3.Icons.developers.svg") };
```

Comment: SVG format is a standard image file that windows recognized.  You need a special viewer for the SVG.

Comment: so you are saying that i can't load the embedded SVG image like i load my PNG image ?, and if so what is a special viewer and any topics on that subject

Comment: the Image control does not support SVG.  for SVGCachedIMage, try using `SvgImageSource`

Comment: Do a search on web for "SVG Viewer".  It is XML format (text) and in some cases the source may be a URL png file.  SVG has layers like a map where you have the contour and then may contain layers showing altitude, rain fall, restaurants.

Comment: @Jason using SvgImageSource with the SVGcached image solved my problem, write it as an answer so i can mark it as a solution, thx

Comment: @jdweng i am gonna look for that stuff up, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to load an SVG, use [SvgImageSource](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support) with `SvgCachedImage`